# Does Go have a stable compiler API?

Tags: go

Does Go have a stable compiler API? That is, suppose you want to:

1. Parse Go code to an intermediate format
2. Do something (e.g. analysis or optimization) with the code
3. Generate a binary as normal

and you would like to use the existing compiler implementation for steps 1 and 3, is this possible?

To further clarify what I mean: C++ does have a compiler API, thanks to Clang/LLVM, but not a stable one (Clang/LLVM regularly breaks API backward compatibility, or did last I checked), so that's the kind of thing I'm looking for, but hopefully stable.

Comment: Parsing Go code is in the standard library: [`go/xxx`](https://golang.org/pkg/go/) packages. You can also change / manipulate the ast representation. For #3, you could just call / execute the `go` command.

Comment: @icza there is no way to compile an AST. The “stable api” for the compiler is the source code. Any optimizations would be probably be done using the SSA form, which is the closest thing the GC compiler has to an IR.

Comment: Whether you consider the (various) compilers intermediate formats stable or not is your choice. Just take a look at the compiler and the supporting packages.

Comment: @JimB Yes, I didn't say (didn't mean to imply) that AST can be compiled directly. You first have to write the modified AST to files, and you may call the `go` tool to compile those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @icza said in a comment, you may use the [`go/...`](https://golang.org/pkg/go/) packages from the standard library to do this.

The standard library falls under the Go 1 guarantee (API stability).

These packages may see additions and bug fixes to their APIs but not breaking changes, for as long as the major version of Go remains 1.

Read the [guarantee document](https://golang.org/doc/go1compat) for further information and edge cases.